# Google Play Console. Где загрузить версию 2 для тестирования?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Загрузил приложение версии 1 через Google Play Console для альфа тестирования.
Исправил некоторые ошибки. Скомпилировал версию 2 для загрузки. 
Не могу понять куда мне ее загрузить в Google Play Console, чтобы у тестировщиков версия 1 обновилась на версию 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жмите на "Создать выпуск" - там указываете файл, описание релиза и прочее и жмёте "Опубликовать" - версия обновится и тестировщики смогут автоматически обновится.